# How to resolve expected identifier and ':' expected error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a surprising error from nowhere and I don't know how to solve it. It needs an identifier and ':'.
How can I solve it?

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child:( _futureUser == null)
            ? Column(
                children: <Widget>[...]
)//column
)//Here I have an error //Container
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the else expression by adding the `:` 
Try this :

```
Container(
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
   child:( _futureUser == null)? Column(children: <Widget>[...]):Container()
),
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have accidently added a [conditional expression](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions) when you have a `?` in front of your `Column`. If you want to show the `Column` regardless of whether `_futureUser` is null remove the `( _futureUser == null) ?`, but if you want to show a different widget if that statement is false than add a `:` after the Column and declare you other widget. You may want to display nothing if `_futureUser==null`, in which case add a `: Container()` after the Column.